# Is the anyway that can I override the header and footer setting of docxcompose module?

Tags: python, docx

I am trying to to merge multiple docx files using docxcompose but unfortunately the all other docx file is inheriting from master docx file. Is there anyway to change that setting ?
Here is my sample code

```
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
   master = Document('template.docx')
   composer = Composer(master)
   doc2 = Document('test.docx')
   composer.append(doc2)
   composer.save("final_output.docx")
```